# Dropped database with rake db:schema:load. Any way to recover data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, disaster-recovery, postgresql-9.6

I just made a huge mistake by doing a  rake db:schema:load on my production rails server (which resets the postgres database)

I have a backup from a day ago, but there's still a lot of critical data I'll be missing from the last 24 hours including transaction data.

I'm running postgres 9.6, I've looked at past  stackoverflow posts, but I don't know if the data is still there somewhere

I stopped postgres as soon as I found out(maybe 10 mins after I issued the command)

There are some WAL files in the  "pg_xlog" directory, is it possible to recover from them?

I also saw this post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49118 that says there's a way to inspecting the pageinspect module.

Is there any way to get a sql transaction history or something from the last 24 hours?

I wanted to ask this question first before restarting postgres and maybe killing whatever chance I had.

Thanks

Comment: Touch nothing. Run, don't walk, to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, just posted there. I'm going through HTTP logs now, but it seems pretty futile to get much from there. It's a 80G database, as well so I'm hoping there wasn't much time for postgres to permanently delete everything and the data's still out there.